# AEM adaptive forms repeat email validation

Tags: aem, aem-6

I'm working on creating adaptive form on AEM. I'm new in AEM forms topic and I would like to create a form which includes validation type "please repeat the same email". I see that AEM adaptive forms doesn't have such feature by default. I'm thinking how can I achieve that. I don't know how to "attack" this problem. Should I create specific rules? Attach clientlib for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation can be achieved using the rule editor (either the visual or the code editor should be able to achieve your requirement) within the form. However, your business users need to have knowledge of using those editors if they wish to maintain/make changes going forward.

Alternatively, you can add it to a clientlib and attach it to the form. This would allow you to version control the code as well as provide an easy way for the authors to reuse this validation in multiple forms if necessary.